# Error al instalar docker

Tags: github, docker, windows10, wsl

Tengo este gran problema al instalar docker a pesar de haber puesto en practica todo lo relacionado con el tema, probé con actualizaciones y verifiqué que mi ordenador cumpliera con las especificaciones requeridas para la instalación de Docker.

```
Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error

An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command. Common causes include acces ridhts issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.

Please try shutting WSL down(wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting you computer. If not sufficient. WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resor, Try to unninstall/reinstall Docker.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. He realizado varios cambios para intentar ayudar a que este publicación cumpla mejor con las regles de este sitio. Estas se explican de forma muy concisa y simple en el [tour]. Para poderte ayudar, debes de proporcionar más datos, no demasiados, sólo los mínimos indespensables para poder reproducir el error con el que estás solicitando ayuda.

Comment: Quizás te ayude imaginar que vas a tratar de reproducir el problema en otro equipo.